# How to hide auto incremented property while creating model in Entity Framework code-first

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In Entity Framework, I have created a `Department` class which has an auto-incremented `DepartmentId`, and `ICollection` of `Employees`.

I don't want anyone see these two properties while creating the object of `Department` class. Can anyone help?

I tried using access modifier but that didn't work.

```
public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}


using (var ctx = new EmployeeContext())
{
    var department = new Department()
        {
                DepartmentName = "Engineering",
        };

    ctx.Departments.Add(department);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

When a user is doing

```
var department = new Department()
```

then `department.DepartmentId` and `department.Employees` should not be available.

Comment: `I don't want anyone see these two properties` Why?

Comment: @mjwills because DepartmentId is auto incremental using EF. and even if i set it, it will use deafault DepartmentId.

Comment: @Stefan Can you please help to match to my scenario.

Comment: Please try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619955/mapping-private-property-entity-framework-code-first#21686896

Comment: Thanks @Stefan the second link actually helped, please add to the solution to this question. Just one small problem, extending the question. When I am making Employees private it works. But at the same time, if I am making the EmployeeId private in Employee class, It is throwing this error: Employees: EntityType: EntitySet 'Employees' is based on type 'Employee' that has no keys defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly when you want to achieve is abstracting the `POCO Department Class`.

Well you can try creating a `ViewModel` for example:

```
public class DepartmentViewModel
{
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}
```

Then Show or Get Database base this `ViewModel`, However if you want to Get the POCO Object from your for example : `Dbset.Find()` method or vice versa, you need to fill the object base on other object OR use Mappers such as `AutoMapper`. lets say you have an object from DepartmentViewModel called vm like below:

```
var vm = new DepartmentViewModel(); //<---- this is an example
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<DepartmentViewModel, Department>();
});
IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
//entity is a POCO Department Object. 
var entity = mapper.Map<DepartmentViewModel, Department>(vm);
//here you can pass the entity to EF for insert. 
using (var ctx = new EmployeeContext())
{
    ctx.Departments.Add(entity);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Then as explained you can easily map it using Automapper, as you can see `entity` is now your `Department object` and you can do the vice versa by changing the `DepartmentViewModel` with `Department` in config.

And don't forget to download AutoMapper from nuget:

> Install-Package AutoMapper -Version 8.1.1

Answer (score 0):

You can use backing fields feature.

**Entity framework core**

```cs
public class Department
{
    private int _departmentId { get; set; }

    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    private ICollection<Employee> _employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    private int _employeeId { get; set; }

    public Department Department;
}
```

and now in your `DbContext` class

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().HasKey("_departmentId");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().Property<int>("_departmentId");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Department>(c =>
        c.HasMany(typeof(Employee), "_employees")
            .WithOne("Department")
    );

    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasKey("_employeeId");

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

**Entity framework 6.2.0**

```cs
public class Employee
{
    private int _employeeId { get; set; }

    public Department Department { get; set; }

    public class EmployeeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Employee>
    {
        public EmployeeConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(d => d._employeeId);
        }
    }
}

public class Department
{
    private int _departmentId { get; set; }

    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    private ICollection<Employee> _employees { get; set; }

    public class DepartmentConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Department>
    {
        public DepartmentConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(d => d._departmentId);
            Property(d => d._departmentId);
            HasMany(d => d._employees).WithOptional(e => e.Department);
        }
    }
}
```

and now in your `DbContext` class

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    modelBuilder.Configurations
        .Add(new Department.DepartmentConfiguration())
        .Add(new Employee.EmployeeConfiguration());

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

I had tried this code and it works.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. But getting this error, after making the changes you suggested. Error: "configure the primary key property(s) for this entity type". I am using .net entity framework 6.2.0

Comment: I have updated the code for entity framework 6.2.0 and also i have made tests and it works fine. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Backing fields are an option, however I don't recommend them for PKs given you are likely going to want to be able to select data by PK and the PK won't be exposed by the entity.  For instance you might want to check child data using:

```
var employeesInDepartment = context.Employees
    .Where(x => x.Department.DepartmentId == departmentId)
    .ToList()
```

or

```
var employeesInDepartment = context.Departments
    .Where(x => x.DepartmentId == departmentId)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Employees)
    .ToList();
```

This won't be available if your Department ID is completely hidden. You can leverage `.Find` which will use the mapped PK, however, this is less practical because `Find` will always load the entity, where `Select` can be more selective about the data you want to retrieve. You'll also want PKs to send to the UI so that you can associate data coming back to their respective entities on the return trip. For instance when I create a new employee, it will be associated to a department. I send back a DepartmentID to associate, not disconnected entities. Sending entities is a performance and security trap, and even if you did want to serialize entities across, private backing fields would not be transferred so a Department entity coming back would lack any PK, rendering it useless.

Instead of trying to hide the property, you can guard the Setters by making them Private.

```
public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; private set; }
    // ...
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; private set; } = new List<Employee>();
}
```

This way you can still take advantage of accessing these properties in Linq expressions without implying they can be set. Collection references should never expose setters to avoid issues where someone tries clearing a child collection by setting the collection to a new List.

Note: This solution still will not allow you to receive entities from the client because the private setter will prevent deserialization. This is a good thing, as it will help ensure that your project does get corrupted to accept entities from the client. I cover the implications of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55926639/how-to-include-mapped-entity-to-notmapped-entity/55929508#55929508).